# Add condition rule to collection product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, catalog-rules

[image: this is condition rule]

I want to add condition rule in the collection product. How to do that. Hope someone help me.[![

> ```
> public function getLoadedProductCollection()
> {
>         $this->_limit = (int) $this->getWidgetCfg('limit');
>         $type = $this->getTypeFilter();
>         $fn = 'get' . ucfirst($type) . 'Products';
>         $collection = $this->{$fn}();
> ```

```
        if ($this->_stockConfig->isShowOutOfStock() != 1) {
            $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

        }
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
            ['collection' => $collection]
        );

    $conditions = $this->getConditions();
    $conditions->collectValidatedAttributes($collection);
    $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($collection, 
    $conditions);

    return $collection;
}
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjQu4.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjQu4.png)
[[image: this is collection]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEBuJ.png)

[image: this is the product.I did insert in home page]

[image: this is an error]